# iOS7: Mobile web app isn't showing changed image

Tags: ios, html, caching, web-applications

Somehow my iPad mini is doing some weird caching.

I made a web page and inserted html code with a wrong src path. I tried to load the page on the mobile web app (after adding it to home screen) and it didn't work (as expected). I fixed the path and the image now shows on all browsers, including the Safari web browser, but not if I open the web app from home screen.

My HTML is simply this:

```
<img src="images/games/oplossing.png" alt="de oplossing"/>
```

The surrounding div is set to 'display: none' but gets set to 'display: block' after clicking a button.

I also tried to:

- link to absolute path
- Delete the app from homescreen and add to homescreen

If I alter the HTML, save change some text, it shows me the change. This means the page is not cached but somehow the broken image link is..

Comment: **1.)** Try manually typing the full path of the image file itself to see if the mobile browser can resolve it. **2.)** Create a tag pair for the `<img>` tag instead of using a single `<img>` tag, some browsers don't like that. **3.)** Create a new file with that image to eliminate the possibility of strange caching behavior.

Comment: Your third solution did the job. It's still strange it caches broken links. Thanks!

Comment: Ehh.. Unless told otherwise browsers will do everything they possibly can to avoid that extra GET request. They love `HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified` and thank god when a page doesn't have a single instance of `XMLHttpRequest`. When something doesn't work, look at caching first. Browsers can cache in really bazaar ways...